# Jquery click event on D3 path

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am using D3 for the first time to present a map of all the US congressional district. I also want to use jquery in tandem with D3. I can not capture a click event in jquery for the paths for each district. Each path has a class assigned to it of "district". However, $(".district").click wont fire. I have even tried assigning each path an id and selecting it in jquery that way. How can I use jquery to fire when a path is clicked? The paths are in an SVG object.

D3 Code Below:

```
svg.append("defs").append("path")
.attr("id", "land")
.datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
.attr("d", path);

svg.append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip-land")
.append("use")
.attr("xlink:href", "#land");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "districts")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)")
.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.feature(congress, congress.objects.districts).features)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class","indiv_district")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("id", function(d) {  
    if(d.id !== undefined) {
        return convert_fips_district(d.id); 
    }
})

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "district-boundaries")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(congress, congress.objects.districts, function(a, b) { return (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0); }))
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "state-boundaries")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("d", path);
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(".indiv_district").on( "click", function() {
alert("here");
});
```

Comment: can you provide the code that draws the line and assigns the class as well as the jquery code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only posted part of the D3 code, I could not test directly on your code, but I have a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8f3dJ/1/) of how a this can be done on the [line chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) from the D3 gallery.

The general strategy is exactly the same as the one you have used, this idea should work fine, but there are a couple of things to be aware of:

#### A single pixel wide path is very hard to click.

In the example you can click both the graph data-line (blue) and the x-axis, but it is very hard to click the x-axis, since it is so narrow.

#### You have to specify in the css if you want a "hand"-style cursor to appear on hover.

If you don't have this kind of feedback, it's hard to know if you have clicked the right element on screen. Try to give the path a cursor property in the css.

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Hope this helps and that you get your code to work the way you want. If you still cant find the error, I would like to help further, but I would need you to either post all your D3 drawing code and css, or make a JSFiddle with the bug present.